# Unable to write on to the External SD card in Android

Tags: android, file-io, storage, android-sdcard

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                // Write to SD Card
                fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/camtest");
                if(!file.exists())
                    file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);

                resetCam();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };
```

With this code i am able to store into Device Storage.

DeviceStorage/Emulated/0/camtest

I want to store it on to the external SD card. How do i do this

I have the following permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Make sure the device isn't rooted via USB when you're testing.

Comment: Hi @Hank No my device isnt rooted

Comment: does it log the wroteBytes line?

Comment: Yes @superfell It did log the wroteBytes line with size as well

Comment: @superfell i am also able to access the files written from file Manager

Answer (score 0):

This  is code I have in a class that I use to take a picture and save it to a folder on my sdcard

```
makeOutPutFolder();

    Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Requesting capture");
            cameraView.capture(new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    Log.v("Still", "Image data received from camera");
                    try {
                        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "student_images");       
                        if (!exportDir.exists())
                        {
                            exportDir.mkdirs();
                        }
                        Log.d("Still image filename:", "capture.jpg");
                        File file = new File(exportDir + File.separator + STILL_IMAGE_FILE);
                         FileOutputStream WriteStudentImage = new FileOutputStream(file);
                       WriteStudentImage.write(data);
                       WriteStudentImage.close();
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished Saving Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       //updateImageCount(currentAnimal);
                       finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Still", "Error writing file", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
 }

public void makeOutPutFolder(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
                //We can read and write the media
                mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
                 //             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We Can Read And Write ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                         +File.separator
                         +"student_images"); //folder name
                         file.mkdir();
            } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)){
                  mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
                  mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
              //                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We Can Read but Not Write ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }else{
                    //something else is wrong
                    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
                     //                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We Can't Read OR Write ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
}
```

Comment: Even with your code it is still saving into phone's directory. I tried restarting my device as well.---@Hank

Comment: @Hank-- I have uncommented the toast to see the message and it says "We can Read and Write". After the picture is taken it quits out from the application

Comment: Oh may be because i have finish it quits on my face